# use of returning $this inside a method

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, laravel-5, autocomplete

I am using Laravel and eclipse as my IDE. I am using the laravel-ide-helper package for autocompletion.

I am calling methods from an eloquent model object.

When I type in

```
User::find
```

eclipse provided me with:

find($id, $columns) : \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.

which means the "find" method returns an \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model instance.

However, when I type in

```
User::where
```

eclipse provided me with the following:

```
where($column, $operator, $value, $boolean) : $this
```

which means the function "where" returns

```
$this
```

Now, I don't really know what $this means because as I understand it "where" should return a query builder instance. As far as I know, $this means the object caller of the method (in this context, the User model itself). But it clearly does not return the model. I suspect that I do not understand what $this means in this context.

What am I missing?

Comment: In this case, `$this` is the Query Builder. Check out the [Laravel Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) documentation.

Comment: @Stephen Lake ah ok. But isn't it the ide and autocompletions job to inform me what object a particular method would return? What's odd is for methods like find, eclipse says it returns illuminate\database\eloquent\Model. Why only $this in where?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to answer that, I don't use that third-party autocomplete package, but I've a feeling it's just not intelligent enough to provide you with that information. Although... the query builder kind of is the model instance as well, so returning itself does make sense, but it'd probably be best you Google'd more information on the query builder and model inheritance because it would take a while to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find()` and `where()` methods do *not* exist on the Model class, so calls to these methods ends up falling through to the PHP magic method `__call()` which Laravel *has* defined. Inside this magic method, Laravel forwards the method call to a new query builder object, which *does* have these methods.

The query builder class' `find()` method returns a Model, and its `where()` method returns a reference to itself ($this) so that you can fluently chain more method calls to the builder.

All of this can make it hard for an IDE to provide hints (IntelliSense), which is where packages like laravel-ide-helper come in. They basically generate files full of interfaces that your IDE can use to understand what magic methods and properties exist for various classes, but in some cases these method signatures still fall short of what you might like to know about the code structure.

In this case the IntelliSense suggestions are apparently populating from the docblock for `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::where()`:

```
/**
 * Add a basic where clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string|array|\Closure  $column
 * @param  mixed   $operator
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @return $this
 */
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and');
```

You can see that the return type is defined as `$this`. At this point, some IDEs may be smart enough to understand the meaning and provide suggestions for an instance of that class. However, this could become more complicated if the method definitions your IDE is parsing are being generated by packages like laravel-ide-helper. In that case it depends not only on the capabilities of your IDE, but also on the output of the helper package.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse works purely off the method comments in the source code for its hints, so if you look at the source code for [`Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) which is the returned type of `query()`, it has for `find`...

```
/**
     * Find a model by its primary key.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]|static|null
     */
    public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
```

for `where()` it is...

```
/**
     * Add a basic where clause to the query.
     *
     * @param  string|\Closure  $column
     * @param  string  $operator
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @param  string  $boolean
     * @return $this
     */
    public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
    {
```

As it can only add one type hint it uses the first from `find()` which is `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and the only option from `where()` is `$this`.